# im trying to setup a tor server using golang and the echo framework

Tags: go

I'm trying to setup a tor server using golang and the echo framework. I'm really stuck. I know I have to use socks 5 and a dialer but I don't know how to put that in to echo. I know I can do it using standard libs but I want to do it in echo. Could any one help

```
const (
    torProxyAddr = "127.0.0.1:9050"
    )

     func GetHttpClient() *http.Client {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", torProxyAddr, nil, proxy.Direct)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to tor proxy : " + err.Error())
    }
    transport := &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return dialer.Dial(network, addr)
        },
    }
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to create cookie jar : " + err.Error())
    }
    return &http.Client{Transport: transport, Jar: jar}
     }

    func main() {

    c := GetHttpClient()

    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))

       }
```

I'm just really unsure of what to do. I cant find any documents on the echo frame main site and there are no git repos that are still in service doing this